# How do I convert this checksum code from C# to Java?

Tags: c#, java

I need help converting this code from C# to Java.

```
    public static ulong GetChecksum(byte[] data)
    {
        ulong sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in data)
            sum += item;

        return ulong.MaxValue - sum + 1;
    }
```

The Java version would return long, instead ulong.

Edit: I haven't tried anything, because I don't know how to handle the last line ulong.MaxValue. Basically, what I need for the end result is to produce the same number that is (long)GetChecksum(buffer) in C# to be the same as getChecksum(buffer) in java.
I'm very new to java, which is why I ask this.

Edit2: Here is the final solution. Many helpful comments. Thank you guys.

```
public static byte[] getChecksum(byte[] data) {
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (byte s : data)
            sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long) ((char) s & 0xFF)));

        return new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16).subtract(sum).add(BigInteger.ONE).toByteArray();
    }
```

Edit2: Too bad this question got downrated. It has many useful comments.

Comment: what problems are you having? Java and C# are so similar already, and this is a pretty simple function....

Comment: `byte` is unsigned in C#, so what would be the appropriate type to use in Java? The `foreach` loop in C# does not exist in Java, what would be the appropriate construct to replace it? How are you going to deal with C# returning an unsigned type but returning a signed type in Java? Are you concerned about overflow? (These are the questions you should be considering and googling instead of asking for a stranger to write your conversion.)

Comment: This question is actually quite interesting, because the Java `byte` data type is signed and Java doesn't have an `ulong` data type.

Comment: are you going to be comparing checksums generated with c# against ones for java? because if you are you are going to ruin somebodies day...

Comment: I will be comparing the 8 byte representation of the checksums, so basically yes, I will be comparing the C# checksum (cast in long) to be equal to java checksum.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski: This went to a bad question ("send-me-teh-codez") to a good question when you added your edit.  Lesson for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java does not throw errors on arithmetic overflow, you should be able to do something like:

```
long sum = 0;
for (byte b : data)
    sum += (long) b;

return sum;
```

The return was simplified based on the assumption that you want the exact same result (in binary rather than in value) as in C#. `ulong.MaxValue` is 64 bits of 1, which is -1 in signed long which cancels the "+1".

Edit: I told a lie here. The result should be logically -sum, which due to the default two's compliment implementation, can't be easily done. You should consider the BigInteger solution instead.

Edit2: Because signed subtraction behaves non-uniformly, the unsigned operation `ulong.MaxValue - sum` can't be simulated trivially. What I suggest you do is:

```
long sum = 0;
for (byte b : data)
    sum += ((long) b) & 0xFFL; // To prevent sign-expansion. Sorry, I missed this the first time as well.

return (new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16)).subtract((new BigInteger(Long.toHexString(sum), 16))).add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

This looks ugly but I tried my best to use native arithmetic as much as possible.

You can use BitInteger's "toByteArray()" method to get the raw binary for comparison. Do not use longValue() as it destroys the first bit.

Comment: Thank you, I found the last line confusing too, which is why I asked this. WIll try this code.

Comment: Maybe i'm just missing something but: 100000000-10+1 != 10

Comment: @32bitkid Your comment just proved that you have no idea how computer does arithmetic and you couldn't even bother to Google before you make irresponsible comments. Tomislav Markovski: Make sure you compare the results in binary, e.g. by converting to bytes, so that the first bit is not treated as a sign bit in Java.

Comment: @billc.cn geez! defensive much! I'm fully aware of twos-compliment for storing integers. what about endianness? Its probably *worth* at least a mention rather than your magical "+1". And i'm still pretty sure its not right, but I'm at work so I can't verify.

Comment: @billc.cn and no, I wasn't the one who down voted your previous answer.

Comment: @billc.cn I am comparing the bytes, and both values are converted to byte array using big endian. Will post results soon.

Comment: @Tomislav Markovski See my latest edit. I am trying to work around the two's compliment problem now...

Comment: okay, lets simplify. lets only assume a unsigned byte and the array [1,2,3]. The sum of the array is 6. So `255-5+1==250` or `11111010` which != `6` or `00000101`, but does equal a signed byte `-6` or `11111010`.

Comment: See Edit2. I tried a few test cases, it seems to work fine now. Also take great care about the byte-ordering problem raised by 32bitkid.

Comment: This worked billc.cn. I was using longValue() before I came here and read your solution. I've added the code I'm using to the original post which is heavily downrated for some weird reason. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`ulong` doesn't have an equivalent in  Java. However, you can work around it with [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
private static BigInteger Checksum(short[] data)
{
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;  
    for (short s : data)  
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long)s)); 

    return new BigInteger("18446744073709551615", 10).subtract(sum).add(BigInteger.ONE); 
}
```

Also, since bytes are signed in Java, you have to go up to `short` to get 0-255.

**EDIT**: If your signature needs to match using `byte[]` instead of `short[]`, then [billc.cn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499922/billc-cn) has the answer.

Comment: I just want to say that the cast to short does not solve the sign problem due to sign-expansion.

Comment: @billc.cn Which cast to short? I'm casting to long, but not to short anywhere (that I can see).

Comment: You changed the input to short[] which I believe the poster will implement in a wrapper with cast, which can cause problems. I think we'd better match the signature and handle all the problems inside the function. :)

Comment: billc.cn is correct. The above code needs this modification:
sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf((long) ((char) s & 0xFF)));

Comment: (Yeah, I guess I should change me attitude. I assume too much. Thank you for pointing it out.)